# JPA remove referenced entity causes: org.hibernate.StaleStateException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, java-ee-7

I need to delete all `Text` records which are referencing a specific `Post` record in database, by using JPA. By calling the remove method from the entity manager the delete statement: `delete from TEXT where pk_id=?` is printed twice and the following exception is thrown.

`org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1`

```
14:44:26,495 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (default task-2) ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffffc0a8026a:-7653facf:54abe6a9:15, org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@48c3c965 >: javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapStaleStateException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1800) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1705) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1882) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:115) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:50) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:358) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:91) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1166) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.endTransaction(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:147) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:93) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:52) [narayana-jts-jacorb-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final (revision: 9aa71)]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleMethodInvocation.java:30) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.chain.AbstractInterceptionChain.invokeNext(AbstractInterceptionChain.java:103) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.chain.AbstractInterceptionChain.invokeNextInterceptor(AbstractInterceptionChain.java:81) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:48) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:41) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:53) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at at.pou.postit.dao.repository.TextRep$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.remove(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at at.pou.postit.dao.repository.TextRep$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.remove(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at at.pou.postit.model.TestBean.deletePostOfUser(TestBean.java:242) [classes:]
    at at.pou.postit.model.TestBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deletePostOfUser(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:308) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:269) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:81) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:63) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3400) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3630) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:114) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ... 74 more
```

---

Here are the sources:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import at.pou.postit.dao.repository.base.SingleIdEntity;

@Entity(name = Post.TABLE_NAME)
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Table(name = Post.TABLE_NAME)
public class Post extends SingleIdEntity<Integer> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2351559621688678451L;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "POST";

    @Id
    @Column(name = "pk_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "cDate")
    private Date cDate;

    @Column(name = "mDate")
    private Date mDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    private List<Posting> postings;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    private List<Text> texts;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "POST_CATEGORY", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_postcat_post") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_category") })
    private List<Category> categories;

    protected Post() {

    }

    public Post(final String title, final String description) {
        this(title, description, new Date(), null);
    }

    public Post(final String title, final String description, final Date cDate,
            final Date mDate) {
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setDescription(description);
        this.setcDate(new Date());
        this.setmDate(null);

        this.postings = new ArrayList<Posting>();
        this.texts = new ArrayList<Text>();
        this.categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getcDate() {
        return cDate;
    }

    public void setcDate(Date cDate) {
        this.cDate = cDate;
    }

    public Date getmDate() {
        return mDate;
    }

    public void setmDate(Date mDate) {
        this.mDate = mDate;
    }

    public List<Text> getTexts() {
        return texts;
    }

    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void addToCategory(Category cat) {
        if (!categories.contains(cat)) {
            categories.add(cat);
            cat.addPost(this);
        }
    }

    public void removeFromCategory(Category cat) {
        categories.remove(cat);
        cat.removePost(this);
    }

    /**
     * Keep this method protected since this list gets maintained by the
     * corresponding OWNER {@link Text} instances.
     * 
     * @param text
     *            {@link Text}
     */
    protected void addText(Text text) {
        this.texts.add(text);
    }

    /**
     * @see Post#addText(Text)
     * @param text
     *            {@link Text}
     */
    protected void removeText(Text text) {
        this.texts.remove(text);
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import at.pou.postit.dao.repository.base.SingleIdEntity;

@Entity(name = Text.TABLE_NAME)
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Table(name = Text.TABLE_NAME)
public class Text extends SingleIdEntity<Integer> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1664519900851671460L;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "TEXT";

    @Id
    @Column(name = "pk_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "subTitle")
    private String subTitle;

    @Column(name = "subDescription")
    private String subDescription;

    @Column(name = "cDate")
    private Date cDate;

    @Column(name = "mDate")
    private Date mDate;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinTable(name = Text.TABLE_NAME)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_text_post")
    private Post post;

    protected Text() {

    }

    public Text(final String subTitle, final String subDescription,
            final String content) {
        this.setSubTitle(subTitle);
        this.setSubDescription(subDescription);
        this.setcDate(new Date());
        this.setmDate(null);
        this.setContent(content);
        this.post = null;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getSubTitle() {
        return subTitle;
    }

    public void setSubTitle(String subTitle) {
        this.subTitle = subTitle;
    }

    public String getSubDescription() {
        return subDescription;
    }

    public void setSubDescription(String subDescription) {
        this.subDescription = subDescription;
    }

    public Date getcDate() {
        return cDate;
    }

    public void setcDate(Date cDate) {
        this.cDate = cDate;
    }

    public Date getmDate() {
        return mDate;
    }

    public void setmDate(Date mDate) {
        this.mDate = mDate;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Post getPost() {
        return post;
    }

    public void setPost(final Post post) {
        if (this.post != null) {
            this.post.removeText(this);
        }
        this.post = post;

        if (this.post != null) {
            this.post.addText(this);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here, the method called from `TestBean`:

```
public void deleteTextOfPosting() {
    Posting posting = postingRep.find(userId, postId);
    if (posting == null) {
        return;
    }
    Post p = postRep.findByIdEager(posting.getPost().getId());

    /*
     * Although there is a foreach loop, the post just contains a single
     * Text instance.
     */
    for (Text t : p.getTexts()) {
        System.out.println("Text-instance: " + t.toString());
        t.setPost(null);
        textRep.remove(t); // Here the exception is thrown!!!
    }
}
```

And here the overridden remove method from `textRep`:

```
@Override
public boolean remove(E entity) {
    if (entity == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!this.entityManager.contains(entity)) {
        if (!isIdSet(entity)) {
            return false;
        }

        entity = findById(entity.getId());
        if (entity == null) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    this.entityManager.remove(entity);
    return true;
}
```

The logged SQL statements:

```
15:14:42,867 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: select posting0_.pk_id as pk_id1_3_, posting0_.allowSharing as allowSha2_3_, posting0_.grantFromUser as grantFro3_3_, posting0_.owner as owner4_3_, posting0_.fk_perm as fk_perm6_3_, posting0_.fk_posting_post as fk_posti7_3_, posting0_.private as private5_3_, posting0_.fk_user as fk_user8_3_ from POSTING posting0_ inner join POST post1_ on posting0_.fk_posting_post=post1_.pk_id inner join USER user2_ on posting0_.fk_user=user2_.pk_id where user2_.pk_id=? and post1_.pk_id=?

15:14:42,961 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: select permission0_.pk_id as pk_id1_1_0_, permission0_.perm as perm2_1_0_ from PERMISSION permission0_ where permission0_.pk_id=?

15:14:42,982 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: select post0_.pk_id as pk_id1_2_0_, post0_.cDate as cDate2_2_0_, post0_.description as descript3_2_0_, post0_.mDate as mDate4_2_0_, post0_.title as title5_2_0_ from POST post0_ where post0_.pk_id=?

15:14:43,020 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: select user0_.pk_id as pk_id1_6_0_, user0_.eMail as eMail2_6_0_, user0_.fName as fName3_6_0_, user0_.failedLogins as failedLo4_6_0_, user0_.lName as lName5_6_0_, user0_.lastLogin as lastLogi6_6_0_, user0_.lastPwdChange as lastPwdC7_6_0_ from USER user0_ where user0_.pk_id=?

15:14:43,900 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: select post0_.pk_id as pk_id1_2_0_, post0_.cDate as cDate2_2_0_, post0_.description as descript3_2_0_, post0_.mDate as mDate4_2_0_, post0_.title as title5_2_0_ from POST post0_ where post0_.pk_id=?

15:14:43,914 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: select categories0_.fk_postcat_post as fk_postc1_2_0_, categories0_.fk_category as fk_categ2_4_0_, category1_.pk_id as pk_id1_0_1_, category1_.description as descript2_0_1_, category1_.name as name3_0_1_ from POST_CATEGORY categories0_ inner join CATEGORY category1_ on categories0_.fk_category=category1_.pk_id where categories0_.fk_postcat_post=?

15:14:43,937 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: select texts0_.fk_text_post as fk_text_7_2_0_, texts0_.pk_id as pk_id1_5_0_, texts0_.pk_id as pk_id1_5_1_, texts0_.cDate as cDate2_5_1_, texts0_.content as content3_5_1_, texts0_.mDate as mDate4_5_1_, texts0_.fk_text_post as fk_text_7_5_1_, texts0_.subDescription as subDescr5_5_1_, texts0_.subTitle as subTitle6_5_1_ from TEXT texts0_ left outer join TEXT texts0_1_ on texts0_.pk_id=texts0_1_.pk_id where texts0_.fk_text_post=?

15:14:45,662 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Text-instance: Text{id=6}

15:14:57,545 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: select text0_.pk_id as pk_id1_5_0_, text0_.cDate as cDate2_5_0_, text0_.content as content3_5_0_, text0_.mDate as mDate4_5_0_, text0_.fk_text_post as fk_text_7_5_0_, text0_.subDescription as subDescr5_5_0_, text0_.subTitle as subTitle6_5_0_, post1_.pk_id as pk_id1_2_1_, post1_.cDate as cDate2_2_1_, post1_.description as descript3_2_1_, post1_.mDate as mDate4_2_1_, post1_.title as title5_2_1_ from TEXT text0_ left outer join TEXT text0_1_ on text0_.pk_id=text0_1_.pk_id left outer join POST post1_ on text0_.fk_text_post=post1_.pk_id where text0_.pk_id=?

15:14:57,581 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: delete from TEXT where pk_id=?

15:14:57,604 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: delete from TEXT where pk_id=?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping for `Text#post` is wrong. You have both `@JoinTable` and `@JoinColumn` annotations, when you should have one or the other. Since this is a `@ManyToOne` relation and considering that you put the same table (`Text.TABLE_NAME`) as join table, I guess `@JoinTable` is not needed so it should look like this

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_text_post")
private Post post;
```

Once this is fixed, I think the exception will go away.